# Cannot make sums of cell after exporting DevExpress grid to Excel

Tags: excel, gridview, devexpress

I'm trying to export a DevExpress grid in Excel. The trouble I'm having is that either I export the grid in text mode which preservesthe formating I have previously applied to the grid but prevents me from doing some sums on columns (because they the cells are considered text and not values),  OR, I export in value mode which allows me to later do sums in the excel file but loses the formatingthat I had previously applied.
I would like to BOTH keep the formating that I have previously applied on grid AND be able to do sums on columns.
This is one of the ways I've tried to export the grid:

```
Using link As New PrintableComponentLink(New PrintingSystem())

                Dim options As New XlsxExportOptionsEx
                options.ExportType = DevExpress.Export.ExportType.DataAware
                options.TextExportMode = TextExportMode.Value 'Should set to Value to be able to have the numbers      displayed as numbers instead of text.
                options.AllowCellMerge = DefaultBoolean.False

                link.Component = gcInvisibleDetail
                link.CreateDocument(link.PrintingSystem)
                link.ExportToXlsx(tbRepertoire.Text & "\Charges.xlsx", options)

End Using
```

Comment: you can display the type of formatting applied to the grid ?

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, yes, I'm able to see the formatting in the grid.  However, I'm just unable to keep the formatting and have the cell export as values instead of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up just using the following line that fixed all my problems: `gridview.ExportToXlsx(file)`